# Converting python2 byte/string encoding to python3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, byte, pyserial

I'm communicating over a serial port, and currently using python2 code which I want to convert to python3. I want to make sure the bytes I send over the wire are the same, but I'm having trouble verifying that that's the case.

In the original code the commands are sent like this:

```
serial.Serial().write("\xaa\xb4" + chr(2))
```

If I `print "\xaa\xb4"` in python2 I get this: ��.
If I `print("\xaa\xb4")` in python3 I get this: ª´

Encoding and decoding seem opposite too:

Python2: `print "\xaa".decode('latin-1')` -> ª
Python3: `print("\xaa".encode('latin-1'))` -> `b'\xaa'`

To be crude, what do I need to send in `serial.write()` in python3 to make sure exactly the same sequence of `1`s and `0`s are sent down the wire?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `bytes` sequence.

```
ser.write(b'\xaa\xb4')
```

Comment: But if I construct the command like this: `a = '\xaa'`, how would I pass that to `write()`? `print(bytes(a, 'utf8')) -> b'\xc2\xaa'`

Comment: Normally you wouldn't; you'd use `bytes` in the first place. If for some reason you have text and you need to convert the first 256 characters to bytes then you can use the `latin-1` codec.

Comment: Yea thanks. Constructing with `b'\xaa'` and so on has made everything easier. I've realised my problem is with `chr()` and `ord()`.